# Regular expression to match text between specific keywords

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regular expression that matches the text between the keywords .if .else .elseif and .endif

Example:

```
.if CONDITION1
code1
.elseif CONDITION2
code2
.else
code3
.endif
```

Ideally, the regular expression would just match code1, code2 and code3, but it is ok if it matches the text after the keywords as well (CONDITION1, CONDITION2...).

I've tried the following regex:

```
(?:\.if|\.else)(.*?)(?:\.else|\.endif)
```

but it misses code2

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VS7ioj/1)

The regular expression has to work as well when there is no .elseif and/or .else.

Comment: I added an OR --> `(?:\.if|\.else)` `|` `(.*?)(?:\.else|\.endif)`. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: No, this does not work

Comment: In general, are `'.elseif'`'s and `'.else'` necessarily present? Might `'.elseif ...'` appear more than once? Do wish to confirm that lines `'.if' ...`, `'.elseif ...'`'s, `'.else'` and `'.endif'` are present and in the correct order, or do just want lines the don't begin with those strings (and assume those lines are present and in the correct order)?

Comment: What tool or language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you are effectively trying to capture an overlapping match from the `if` to the `elseif` clause. You can workaround that by making the final group in your regex a lookahead instead.

```regex
(?:\.if|\.else(?:if)?)(.*?)(?=\.else|\.endif)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/z4WejJ/1)

Note in terms of avoiding capturing the conditions (or simplifying post-processing them out), you would need to change the first group of the regex to allow for an optional `if` after the `.else`. I've made that change above, but it's not strictly necessary to make the regex work as yours currently does.

If the condition only occurs on the same line as the `.if`/`.elseif`, you can use @CarySwoveland's idea (see comments) to avoid capturing the condition:

```regex
(?:\.if|\.else(?:if)?).*\r?\n([\s\S]*?)(?=\.else|\.endif)
```

This requires removing the `DOTALL` flag. See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/FQqDvW/1).

Comment: Your regex works as expected! Unfortunately, I just realized, that it (of course!) doesn't work if the whole thing is nested inside another .if .. .endif. I guess it is not possible to handle that with a regex and I'll have to parse it manually...

Comment: @osiris81 yeah, unfortunately in general regex is very poor at nested structures. Some languages do support recursive regex but in general such structures are more easily manually parsed.

Comment: @osiris81 if you also capture the opening part (`if/else/elseif`) you can probably reconstruct the hierarchy after matching with this regex

Comment: @CarySwoveland that's a good point, as long as the condition is one line. I've updated the answer to include it. Thanks!

Comment: @CarySwoveland please don't. Attribution is always necessary. just noticed your answer too, taking a look at it now...

Answer (score 1):

You could match the regular expression

```
^(?![ \t]*\.(?:if|elseif|else|endif)\b).*
```

with the *multiline* flag set (causing `^` and `$` to respectively match the beginning of each line, rather than the beginning and end of the string).

This matches all lines that do not begin with zero or more spaces or tabs followed by `'.if'`, `'.elseif'`, `'.else'` or `'.endif'`. If the string is that shown below the lines containing `'code'` and the empty line are matched.

```
.if CONDITION1
code1  
.elseif CONDITION2
   code2
.code3

     .code4
  .elseif CONDITION3
     code5
  .else
     code6
.endif
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5TeDbW/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^                           # match beginning of line 
(?!                         # begin a negative lookahead
  [ \t]*                    # match zero or more tabs or spaces  
  \.                        # match a period
  (?:if|elseif|else|endif)  # match one of the strings in the non-capture group
  \b                        # match a word boundary
)                           # end negative lookahead
.*                          # match the line
```

Comment: This is a really cool idea, although it will match code outside if/else blocks https://regex101.com/r/5TeDbW/3

Comment: @Nick, yes, one of several shortcomings, one being that it does not check order of `if-then` statements.